# z-index value not working on element?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a hamburger sign on, covered by another div. I want the burger sign to stack on top of everything. So I applied z-index values to the places I thought appropriate. However it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why? Here is my codepen below please take a look.

codepen:

http://codepen.io/tbeckett24/pen/qORBbE

html:

```
<body>
     <div id="photoCover">
       <nav id="menu" class="menu">
           <a href="#" class="menu-trigger"><span>Menu</span></a>
       </nav>
     </div><!--photoCover-->
     <div id="entryMenu"></div><!--entryMenu-->
</body>
```

css:

```
html { 
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%; 
    position: relative;
}
#photoCover {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.menu-trigger {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2%; right: 2%;
    display: block;
    width: 60px; height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
  z-index:3000;
}
.menu-trigger span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%; height: 6px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 0px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.menu-trigger span:before,
.menu-trigger span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    content: '';
}
.menu-trigger span:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-270%);
    transform: translateY(-270%);
}
.menu-trigger span:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(270%);
    transform: translateY(270%);
}
#entryMenu {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```

Comment: please provide a valid example

Comment: It looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/78ixOSx.png) for me, where's the problem? How is it supposed to look?

Comment: what I want is everything to be the same but just the hamburger sign to just sit on top. Is that not possible?

Comment: Both `photoCover` and `entryMenu` are positioned and there is no z-index so we have a tie, in which case HTML source order determines which elements appears at the top, which means entry menu covers the photo cover.

Answer (score 2):

By adding a z-index to the parent-div, I got the "hamburger" on the top layer.

```
#photoCover {
    (...)
    z-index:99;
}
```

I would believe that the reason why, is that both the `#photoCover` and the `#entryMenu` is fixed and in the same place, the `#entryMenu` is on top, because it is added last.

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index to the wrapper div

```
#photoCover {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[Demo URL](http://codepen.io/ran161/pen/dYNyKN)

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index: 1;` for div with id=photoCover.

Comment: An explanation of your solution would be helpful. What was the problem and how did you solve it?